# how to get a port address of a android device for socket programing

Tags: php, android, sockets

i am new to socket programing. can any one please explain me what is port address and how can we get from an android device.I would like to use php server to push my data in to android device.

Comment: you can use any number b/w 1024-65535 (eg port 80 is for http, 25 for smtp )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any port you want above 1024 (the OS reserves those top 1025 on Linux for official services).  Your problem will be that if you're on cellular networks you won't be able to connect to the phone, the cellular network is very unlikely to let incoming connections through.  And if you're on wifi you're almost certainly firewalled as well.  Its only likely to work if both the server and the device are on the same wifi network.